# Handling Axios error in React

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios

I have a React component that calls a function `getAllPeople`:

```
componentDidMount() {
   getAllPeople().then(response => {
      this.setState(() => ({ people: response.data }));
    });
  }
```

`getAllPeople` is in my `api` module:

```
export function getAllPeople() {
  return axios
    .get("/api/getAllPeople")
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
}
```

I think this is a very basic question, but assuming I want to handle the error in my root component (in my `componentDidMount` method), not in the `api` function, how does this root component know whether or not I the `axios` call returns an error? I.e. what is the best way to handle errors coming from an `axios` promise?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `getAllPeople` function already returns the data or error message from your `axios` call. So, in `componentDidMount`, you need to check the return value of your call to `getAllPeople` to decide whether it was an error or valid data that was returned.

```
componentDidMount() {
   getAllPeople().then(response => {
      if(response!=error) //error is the error object you can get from the axios call
         this.setState(() => ({ people: response}));
      else { // your error handling goes here
       }
    });
  }
```

If you want to return a promise from your api, you should not resolve the promise returned by your `axios` call in the api. Instead you can do the following:

```
export function getAllPeople() {
  return axios.get("/api/getAllPeople");
}
```

Then you can resolve in `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
   getAllPeople()
   .then(response => {          
         this.setState(() => ({ people: response.data}));
     })
   .catch(error => { 
         // your error handling goes here
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do I not already return `axios.get(...)` from my api, as you suggest?

Comment: Edited my answer with code to clarify what i meant.

Answer (score 73):

Better way to handle **API error with Promise catch method***.

```
axios.get(people)
    .then((response) => {
        // Success
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Error
        if (error.response) {
            // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            // console.log(error.response.data);
            // console.log(error.response.status);
            // console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received
            // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the 
            // browser and an instance of
            // http.ClientRequest in node.js
            console.log(error.request);
        } else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        console.log(error.config);
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

My suggestion is to use a cutting-edge feature of React. [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)

This is an [example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010) of using this feature by Dan Abramov.
In this case, you can wrap your component with this Error Boundary component. 
What is special for catching the error in axios is that you can use 
[interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) for catching API errors. 
Your Error Boundary component might look like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const errorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
  return class EH extends Component {
    state = {
      error: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      // Set axios interceptors
      this.requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
        this.setState({ error: null });
        return req;
      });

      this.responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
        res => res,
        error => {
          alert('Error happened');
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      // Remove handlers, so Garbage Collector will get rid of if WrappedComponent will be removed 
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.requestInterceptor);
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.responseInterceptor);
    }

    render() {
      let renderSection = this.state.error ? <div>Error</div> : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      return renderSection;
    }
  };
};

export default errorHandler;
```

Then, you can wrap your root component passing axios instance with it

```
errorHandler(Checkout, api)
```

As a result, you don't need to think about error inside your component at all.

Comment: This seems to be a good example but I didn't get the `WrappedComponent `, what is it? Also, where to put that `errorHandler(Checkout, api)`?

Comment: my response interceptors is not detecting error of `500`

Comment: Hi @yevhenii , just curious if the api is on the componentDidMount of Checkout. How would the errorHandler catch it if the api isn't exposed to it. Any strategy for that?

Comment: @TOS what do you mean by API? Axios is doing all the calls and there are interceptors for each. Functions that you see in componentDidMount is not API calls, it's more like setting the middleware for each call. 
Yes, you have to pass instance of axios inside

Answer (score 1):

I just combined both answers by [Yevhenii Herasymchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220675/6679820) and [GeorgeCodeHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104469/6679820), fixed some mistakes and ported it into React hooks. So here is my final working version:

```
// [project-directory]/src/lib/axios.js

import Axios from 'axios';

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default axios;
```

```
// [project-directory]/src/components/AxiosErrorHandler.js

import {useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from '@/lib/axios';

const AxiosErrorHandler = ({children}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Request interceptor
    const requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
      // Do something here with request if you need to
      return request;
    });

    // Response interceptor
    const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      // Handle response here

      return response;
    }, (error) => {
      // Handle errors here
      if (error.response?.status) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 401:
            // Handle Unauthenticated here
            break;
          case 403:
            // Handle Unauthorized here
            break;
          // ... And so on
        }
      }

      return error;
    });

    return () => {
      // Remove handlers here
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, []);

  return children;
};

export default AxiosErrorHandler;
```

Usage:

```
// Wrap it around your Layout or any component that you want

return (
  <AxiosErrorHandler>
    <div>Hello from my layout</div>
  </AxiosErrorHandler>
);
```

Comment: How would you set the Authorization header? Would it make sense to extract the request interceptor into the axios library and only have the response interceptor in the error handler? Or add it in the `axios.create({})`, never mind, thinking out loud.

Answer (score 1):

There are  2 options to handle error with axios in reactjs

1. Using catch method:

   ```js
   axios.get(apiUrl).then(()=>{
      //respons
   }).catch((error)=>{
      //handle error here 
   })
   ```
2. try catch

   ```js
   try {
      const res = await axios.get(apiUrl);
   } catch(err){
      //handle error here...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the response before setting it to `state`. Something like

```
componentDidMount() {
   getAllPeople().then(response => {
       // check if its actual response or error
        if(error) this.setState(() => ({ error: response }));
        else this.setState(() => ({ people: response}));
    });
  }
```

Its relying on the fact that `axios` will return different objects for success and failures.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [Yevhenii Herasymchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6805529/yevhenii-herasymchuk) was very close to what I needed however, I aimed for an implementation with functional components so that I could use Hooks and Redux.

First I created a wrapper:

```
export const http = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "/api",
    timeout: 30000,
});

function ErrorHandler(props) {

useEffect(() => {
    //Request interceptor
    http.interceptors.request.use(function (request) {
        // Do something here with Hooks or something else
        return request;
    });

    //Response interceptor
    http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 400) {
            // Do something here with Hooks or something else
            return response;
        }
        return response;
    });
}, []);

return props.children;
}

export default ErrorHandler;
```

Then I wrapped the part of the project that I needed to check how axios behaved.

```
<ErrorHandler>
  <MainPage/>
</ErrorHandler>
```

Lastly, I import the axios instance(http) wherever I need it in the project.

Hope it helps anyone that wishes for a different approach.

Comment: You are not unregistering handlers outside your component