# Authentication works in Insomia/post but does not work in frontend and proceeds to home even without entering wrong user or pass

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

title says it all. even with wrong user inputs the user is allowed to enter the homepage but when I tried checking with insomnia it checks very well if the user is registered in database

this is for the backend

```
router.post("/login", async (req,res) =>{
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({username});

    if (!user) {
        return res.json({message: "User doesn't exist!"});
    }
    const checkpass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if(!checkpass){
        return res.json({message: "Username or Password is Incorrect!"});

    }

    const token = jwt.sign({id: user._id}, "secret");
    res.json({ token, userID: user._id});


});
```

this for the frontend

```
const Auth = (props) => {
  props.funcNav(false)
  

  const [_, setCookies] = useCookies(["access_token"]);

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:5174/auth/login", {
        username,
        password,
      });

      setCookies("access_token", result.data.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("userID", result.data.userID);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: On frontend In case of both error or success navigate("/"); is getting called.

Comment: What do I do to reject user in case of error tahnks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Axios error in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005457/handling-axios-error-in-react)

Comment: I can't make it work